# MATLAB Simple Calculation

Tags: matlab, integer-arithmetic, binary-operators

I am working on MATLAB on my own, and was doing problem 9 on Project Euler 
It states

" A Pythagorean triplet is a set of three natural numbers, a < b < c, for which,

a2 + b2 = c2
For example, 32 + 42 = 9 + 16 = 25 = 52.

There exists exactly one Pythagorean triplet for which a + b + c = 1000.
Find the product abc."

Below is the code I wrote; however, it compiles, but does not produce and output. I was hoping to get some feedback on what's wrong, so I can fix it.

Thanks,

```
syms a;
syms b;
syms c; 
d= 1000;
d=  a + b + c ; 
ab= a.^2 + b.^2; 
ab= c.^2; 
c
```

Comment: It is supposed to perform a *search*. Also your code has no notion of *natural* numbers.

Comment: You need to loop over all possible integers and see if they work. The symbolic math package won't do what you want.

Comment: If you want to do it in a more Matlab-like way (vectorized instead of loops), generate matrices the `1:1000` repeated along rows and along cols via `ndgrid`. Or better yet use `bsxfun` / implicit singleton expansion. `hypot` may be handy

Answer (score 3):

I propose a vectorized way (that is, without using loops) to solve the problem. It may seem relatively complicated, especially if you come from other programming languages; but for Matlab you should get used to this way of approaching problems.

Ingredients:

- [Vectorization](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html);
- [Indexing](https://es.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html);
- [Transpose](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/transpose.html);
- [Implicit singleton expansion](https://nickhigham.wordpress.com/2016/09/20/implicit-expansion-matlab-r2016b/);
- [`hypot`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hypot.html);
- [`find`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html).

Read up on these concepts if you are not familiar with them, and then try to solve the problem yourself (which of course is the whole point of Project Euler). As a hint, the code below proceeds along these lines:

1. Generate a 1×1000 vector containing all possible values for `a` and `b`.
2. Compute a 1000×1000 matrix with the values of `c` corresponding to each pair `a`, `b`
3. From that compute a new matrix such that each entry contains `a+b+c`
4. Find the row and column indices where that matrix equals `1000`. Those indices are the desired `a` and `b` (why?).
5. You'll get more than one solution (why?). Pick one.
6. Compute the product of the obtained `a` and `b` and the corresponding `c`.

Once you have tried yourself, you may want to check the code (move the mouse over it):

> `ab = 1:1000;                      % step 1` 
>  `cc = hypot(ab,ab.');              % step 2` 
>  `sum_abc = ab+ab.'+cc;             % step 3` 
>  `[a, b] = find(sum_abc==1000);     % step 4`  
>  `a = a(1); b = b(1);               % step 5` 
>  `prod_abc = a*b*cc(a,b);           % step 6`